# columns has 2 elements while hbase.columns.mapping has 3 elements error while creating hive table from hbase

Tags: hive, centos, hdfs, hbase, cloudera

I'm getting following error when I run the below command for creating hive table.

sample is my hive table I'm trying to create. hloan is my existing hbase table. Please help.

```
create external table sample(id int, name string)
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES("hbase.columns.mapping"=":key,hl:id,hl:name") 
TBLPROPERTIES ("hbase.table.name"="hloan","hbase.mapred.output.outputtable"="sample");
```

**ERROR:**

```
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. java.lang.RuntimeException: MetaException(message:org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeException org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseSerDe: columns has 2 elements while hbase.columns.mapping has 3 elements (counting the key if implicit))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As error describes your `create external table statement` having **2 columns** **`id,name`**.

In Hbase mapping you are having 3 columns **`:key,hl:id,hl:name`**

**Create table with 3 columns:**

```
hive> create external table sample(key int, id int, name string)
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES("hbase.columns.mapping"=":key,hl:id,hl:name") 
TBLPROPERTIES ("hbase.table.name"="hloan","hbase.mapred.output.outputtable"="hloan");
```

(or)

if `key and id` columns having same data then you can skip **`hl:id`** in mapping.

**Create table with 2 columns:**

```
hive> create external table sample(id int, name string)
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES("hbase.columns.mapping"=":key,hl:name") 
TBLPROPERTIES ("hbase.table.name"="hloan","hbase.mapred.output.outputtable"="hloan");
```